# Objects with the lowest value 0 at the end

Tags: django, django-queryset

The 0 in my query set represent 'unknown' values, but when ordered, they start the list and I want them at the end.

```
table.objects.filter(object=pk).order_by('decimal_coln')
```

This is what I'm getting

```
Object        decimal_coln
Object_kdlsdl 0
Object_nksljj 0
Object_njsdlk 0
Object_jdnskl 1
Object_ldskll 1
Object_nlsdkl 12
Object_sjslkl 15
```

This is what I want (ordered, but zeros at the end):

```
Object        decimal_coln
Object_jdnskl 1
Object_ldskll 1
Object_nlsdkl 12
Object_sjslkl 15
Object_kdlsdl 0
Object_nksljj 0
Object_njsdlk 0
```

Comment: I know is not a direct answer but why don't use NULL for undefined values ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`asc()` expression** - [Djangodoc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression.asc)

> Returns the expression ready to be sorted in **ascending order**.
>
> **`nulls_first`** and **`nulls_last`** define how null values are sorted

```
from django.db.models import F

order_by_expression = F('decimal_coln').asc(nulls_last=True)
table.objects.filter(object=pk).order_by(order_by_expression)
```

[Example can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-to-sort-null-values)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `import F` from `django.db.models` and use in order by column:

```
from django.db.models import F
table.objects.filter(object=pk).order_by(F('decimal_coln').desc(nulls_last=True))
```

Comment: `desc` will return the result in descending order, 15,12,1,1,1,..,0,0. The OP wants to be in 1,1,12,15,...,0,0,0 which is in acseding order.